# Singleton pattern with Browserify/CommonJS

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

Trying to implement the singleton pattern within CommonJS modules, using Browserify. So far:

// foo.js

```
var instance = null;

var Foo = function(){
    if(instance){
        return instance;
    }
    this.num = 0;
    return instance = new Foo();
}

Foo.prototype.adder = function(){
    this.num++;
};

module.exports = Foo();
```

// main.js

```
var foo = require('./foo.js');
console.log(foo.num); // should be 0
foo.adder(); // should be 1
var bar = require('./foo.js');
console.log(bar.num); // like to think it'd be 1, not 0
```

First problem is that I get a `maximum call stack exceeded` error when I load the built JS file in the browser, but secondly, am I approaching this correctly? Is this possible?

Comment: You have an infinite recursion there. `new Foo()` gets evaluated before `instance` is set, which again calls `new Foo()`.. and again.. and again... and ag....

Comment: Singletons are horrible and you probably should not be using them under any circumstance. You're effectively introducing mutable global state into your application.

Comment: modules are effectively singletons, as is mentioned below. singletons are unavoidable. don't know what kind of code you're writing. so you have 1 instance of something, and only need 1. singletons are designed so you, or someone else, don't accidentally create another instance.

Comment: furthermore, with Object.freeze in JavaScript, it allows you to make state immutable. and yes, singletons are often global. you ever used an enumeration with just one value before? give it a shot. in fact module.exports = X is pretty much just that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> First problem is that I get a maximum call stack exceeded error

Well, that comes from your `Foo` function recursively calling `new Foo`…

> but secondly, am I approaching this correctly?

No. For singletons, you don't need a "class" with a constructor and a prototype - there will only ever be one instance. Simply create one object, most easily with a literal, and return that:

```
module.exports = {
    num: 0,
    adder: function(){
        this.num++;
    }
};
```

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Surely when you re-require this, it's going to just give you a new Object Literal?

Comment: @benhowdle89 No it does not, the exported value gets cached.

Comment: Currently eating my words. :)

Comment: Browserify caches modules in a similar fashion to Node.js in some versions, so one cannot really guarantee that a module instance is a singleton. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31111685/browserify-resolves-the-same-file-multiple-times).

Comment: @E_net4: That's weird and looks like a bug to me. Unless you don't mess with the module cache manually, modules should be resolved by (file) location and not the import string. That's how ES6 specifies it.

Comment: You don't NEED a class / prototype but if you use it, debugging is easier and so is passing the instance around in your code because you can see the type of instance it is, named nicely for you. Also for JSDoc comments and intellisense, using a named class instance provides some nice IDE benefits. Just do module.exports = new MyClass();

Answer (score 23):

The result of any require call is a singleton -- whether a singleton instance or a singleton function or a singleton factory function. Furthermore, a require call should be idempotent -- poorly written CommonJS modules may violate this, so if a CommonJS module has a side effect, that side effect should happen only once no matter how many times that require is called.

The code snippet you have

```
if(instance){
    return instance;
}
// ...
return instance = new Foo();
```

is a legacy of the kinds of hoops you'd have to jump through if you were using plain old JavaScript to create singletons. It's totally unnecessary when using CommonJS and besides that, it leads to your `maximum call stack exceeded` issue.

Your code could be rewritten like this:

```
var Foo = function(){
   this.num = 0;
}

Foo.prototype.adder = function(){
   this.num++;
};

module.exports = new Foo();
```

or even more succinctly:

```
module.exports = {
   num: 0,
   adder: function(){ this.num++; }
}
```

because putting the `adder` method on the prototype doesn't gain you any real efficiency if you're only creating a single instance of Foo, and because you don't need to hide anything in the closure.

Comment: I don't even know what's real anymore. This is ace.

Comment: What about if you need to pass options object to constructor ?

Comment: @BigDong In that case, you could always just include an "init" method on the exported object and pass the options that way.