# Backbone.js and Browserify - requiring same module multiple times

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browserify

I am currently working on a Backbone JS application, and I started using Browserify for the first time. But of course I ran into a few problematics. This is one of them.

I have the following module, `/js/views/Home.js`.

```js
var $ = require('jquery'),
    _ = require('underscore'),
    Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;

module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#view',
    template: _.template($('#home-template').html()),
    initialize: function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        this.$el.html(this.template());
    },
    events: {
        'click button': 'searchSubmit'
    },
    searchSubmit: function () {
        // this should be where the magic happens
    }
});
```

When the `searchSubmit` method is called, I want to do something like `router.navigate('search')`.

My question: If I have a router module, `Router.js`, do I then need to create a new instance of it in all of my modules every time I want some router functionality?

```js
var Router = require('./Router.js'),
    router = new Router();
```

It just does not seem logical to create a new router in every view, when Browserify bundles them all together.

Is it me who do not understand Browserify properly, and is there a more clever solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call

```
var Router = require('./Router.js');
```

Browserify is actually keeping track of a single instance of `Router`, so it is not a new instance every time. Think of it as a reference or using statement. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24284554/2589083) for more details.

But with `router = new Router();` you run into a problem of your `router` being instanced. I suggest that in `Router.js` you export an instance of your `router`.

Comment: So, as one of the other answers states, the result of a `require` is a singleton. Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. And if it works, then I suggest accepting my answer so that others will know that your problem is solved.